# Access JsonObject Title from type

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a class with a Json.Net JsonObject attribute, and I've set the Title like so:

```
[JsonObject(Title="SomeOtherClassTitle")]
public class MyClass
{
}
```

I want to be able to access the "SomeOtherClassTitle" title when I'm managing the class as a type. So what I'm aiming for is this but I'm unsure of what

```
var someType = typeof(MyClass);
var customTitle = ??; // Insert code here which returns "SomeOtherClassTitle"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using reflection that can be attained by getting the attribute from the class and calling the desired member

```
var attribute = someType.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(JsonObjectAttribute)) as JsonObjectAttribute;
if(attribute != null) {
    var title = attribute.Title;
}
```